# MySQL user has Host=%, still can't connect remotely

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Even with a Host value of %, I cannot connect remotely to the MySQL container.

```
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.28.0.1' (using passowrd: YES).
```

- I'm using HeidiSQL and the MySQL library to connect
- Noting the IP specified in error message keeps changing which makes it hard to add to Host value
- On Windows 10 using Docker Desktop (4.24.2)
- `my.cnf` does bind to 0.0.0.0.
- Tried different port mappings (ex. 3366:3306)
- Windows Firewall shows Docker Desktop being open to public and private networks

I can connect through Docker Desktop using the Exec tab. I can see that root has appropriate host configured for remote access:

```
mysql> select Host,User from user where User='root';
+-----------+------+
| Host      | User |
+-----------+------+
| %         | root |
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

File: `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    build: './mysql/'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      TZ: "-03:00"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "$MYSQL_DATA:/var/lib/mysql"
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

File: `.env`

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="root"
MYSQL_DATA=C:/Users/me/Downloads/docker_files/mysql/data
```

File: `mysql/Dockerfile`

```
FROM mysql:8.0
COPY conf/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

File `conf/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
user=mysql
bind-address=0.0.0.0
default-time-zone='-03:00'
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log

#setting to 1 per recommendations, need to do this in Azure too.
lower_case_table_names=1

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

HeidiSQL:

[image: heidi sql screen capture]

Update #1

For good measure, I set password for both users using Docker Desktop's terminal:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Still getting access denied.

Comment: Since you are forwarding post 3306, and connecting to localhost, you should be using the password that is set  fro `'root'@'localhost'`, and not the password that is set for `'root'@'%'` (They can be different!)

Comment: I hadn't thought about that! I did go through and reset both passwords to the same value (see update #1). Unfortunately, I keep getting the same results.

Comment: OK, strange things happen, and i did get the same message as you did.  Changing the driver (to limariadb.dll), and saving the connection seems to _solve_ the problem  (even changing the driver back to libmysql.dll and connection still working)

Comment: Maybe this is related to this problem: https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/1838

Comment: No way! It works. I can confirm, changing libraries will fix the connection issue. Out of the box thinking on your part. I never thought the client could be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please submit an answer regarding this being a client issue and I'll accept it.

Comment: You can also create the answer yourself: (see: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)), and filing a bug at HeidiSQL (https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues) would even be better than creating an answer here, but I am too lazy to describe this problem correctly (in English) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that in HeidiSQL, I should always use `libmariadb.dll` even when connecting to MySQL:

https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/1865

Comment: https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/1865#issuecomment-1775361395 says: "No, libmysql.dll is not meant to be used for MySQL, although I admit that may be the first thought.
In fact, **the shipped libmysql.dll is quite old and should only be used for older MySQL and MariaDB servers**, when encountering connection problems with the other libraries.
Instead, if your server version is not older than 10 years, you should use libmariadb.dll,"